# Create a new parse object without data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

Problem: I cannot create new PFObjects objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId: in swift, is this possible and if so how?

Context: I have a stored array of objectIds of parse objects that I want to use to populate a view but first I have to get each object from parse. Rather than making 'n' number of network requests on parse for each object I want to instead make an array of PFObjects using Parse's objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId: functionality and then call [PFObject fetchAllInBackground:block:] with the array. However, in swift it does not appear as though PFObject.objectWithoutDataWithClassname exists. Has anyone encountered this/know how to do this in swift....?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: <String>, objectId: <String?>)
```

This method became an initializer.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! The documentation on Parse's site does not treat it as an initializer.